# Errno 104: Connection reset by peer

Tags: hive, hue, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm trying to open the Hive UI from HUE but I'm getting only the following error from the Web UI :

**[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer**

I've watched into hive and hue logs but no error are reported whatsoever. Anyway Hive is working fine from the command line so I don't understand what's the issue. My HUE version is 2.6.1-2041 and I'm running HDP 2.2.0 with Hadoop 2.6.0 and Hive 0.14.

Same thing happens when I try to open HCatalog.

Comment: Hue 2 submit queries to Beeswax unless you point it to HiveServer2: http://gethue.com/hadoop-tutorial-hive-query-editor-with-hiveserver2-and/. Are they up? You can look on the /desktop/dump_config Hue page to see where Beeswax is pointing.

Comment: In my config file (hue.ini) I don't have any reference to beeswax, I just have hive_server_host and hive_server_port under the [beeswax] section. HiveServer2 is up and running

Comment: ok I've solved the issue, I noticed that actually only hiveserver was running and not hiveserver2 even tho my ambari web interface reported both as running. I just run hive --service hiverserver2 and the error disappeared. Thank you for the support anyway.